# To many IF's. Is there a better way?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have this code:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Dominio\1\Pc - S.txt", "Pc - S - A.txt")
            'Sleep(2000) ' to sleep for 2 second
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Dominio\1\Pc - S - A.txt", "Pc - S.txt")
        End If

        If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Dominio\2\Pc - S.txt", "Pc - S - A.txt")
            'Sleep(2000) ' to sleep for 2 second
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Dominio\2\Pc - S - A.txt", "Pc - S.txt")
        End If
```

And it continues with another 24 if's. I need them to change the name all at the same time and then wait two seconds and change it again all at the same time.Will i need to have 48(24+24) IF's?

Explanation:

Im creating a super simple way of shuting down the computers at my school. Here is my idea(hope you can understand it)

I put a program at every computer at school (in the regestry at the startup) that does the following:
(Atencion not really in a programing language)

for(1){

```
sleep 1000        // wait 1 sec

if.FILE.EXISTS(\\domain\folder1\shutdown.txt) then{

    do: shutdown pc   // if file exist it shutdowns the pc 

}
```

}

So what this does is if there is a file in a certain directory in the domain, it shutsdown the pc.
Im doing this for 24 pcs, so i need to shutdown them individualy, therefor the many folders.
So i could simply rename the files by hand, but for 24 pcs that is a lot of work. So im developing a aplication that asks me what pcs i want to shutdown and then does:

1: Rename file.

2: Wait 2 or more seconds (so the computers in the network have time to verify if there is such file)

3: rename back the file so when the pc restarts it doesnt shutdown again.

Did you get what im trying to do? And yes there are more orthodox ways of doing this. but this is really simple, and this is more of a test than anything. (Later will be using more proper ways of doing this and do other options over the network)

Comment: Where is this data coming from in the first place?  Can you just read it from a text box or something?  Can you make an array of these filenames instead?

Comment: Why are you sleeping for 2 seconds after renaming the file? That seems highly unnecessary?

Comment: Ill edit my post to explain the project. Wait a bit.

Comment: Your edit still didn't make it any clearer. **Why** are you waiting for 2 seconds? And you know this code will not change them all at the same time. Code executes sequentially, line by line.

Comment: wait to seconds because if the network is slow or something if the renaming is to fast the computer verifying if there is such file wont do anything.

what i mean by all at the same time is do all the renaming first, then wait 2 sec then do all the renaming back again.

Comment: Your idea of having a separate program running on all the computers is an absolutely terrible one. That's going to eat up processor time, and be incredibly inefficient and pointless. You know you can remotely shut computers down from your actual program? I'll post an answer to that.

Comment: I know i can but it will take some research and i need this now. Ill do a program like that later, with more knowledge.

And i actually need to make the program close all programs to so yeah..

The programs running dont actually eat  a lot of cpu only about 1%, my concerns is if the network wont get slow.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only difference is a single number in the filepath, why not do something like this?

```
var dict = new Dictionary<CheckBox, string>();
dict.Add(CheckBox1, "1");
dict.Add(CheckBox2, "2");
//etc

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    if(kvp.Key.Checked == true)
    {
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(String.Format("C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Dominio\{0}\Pc - S.txt", kvp.Value ), "Pc - S - A.txt")
    }
}
```

We create a generic dictionary to store the association of the checkboxes to the string/number and then loop through the dictionary, checking the values. We use a format string (you could use string concatenation instead) to insert the string/number into the filepath string.

Note, this is in C#, as I'm not a VB programmer. The syntax will likely be slightly different.

Comment: Hmm it seems a a good idea, but can someone "translate" so to speak this to VB. Im preaty noob in VB. But ill try to search for ways of doing this thanks :)

Comment: You should be able to translate it pretty straight forward if you know anything about VB. Just go through line by line and convert the syntax.

Comment: Yeah, i started doing VB 2 days ago so yeah. It will take a bit of time but will do it :)

Comment: @Jeff Yes, I'm aware of that site and I did attempt to use it, but it choked on some part of the syntax. I'm not worried about it, as translating it by hand should be a piece of cake if you know VB.

Answer (score 0):

Since your intention is to remotely shut down the PC's, why not actually shut them down from your code, rather than some hackish "create files then wait 2 seconds" approach?

Again, this is C# but the translation should be pretty straightforward:

```
var ComputerNames = new List<string>() {"Computer1", "Computer2", "Computer3"};

foreach(var pc in ComputerNames)
{
    Process.Start("shutdown","-s -m \\\\" + pc);
}
```

Comment: That seams simple enough. Will it work if i want to close all open programs? (programs not services or processes)

Comment: When a computer begins the shutdown process, it sends a signal to the program that the PC is shutting down and that the program needs to clean up and exit. It gives the program a certain amount of time to clean up before it hard kills them. Though I believe there are exceptions (such as an open unsaved Notepad document for example). But this should cover the majority of cases anyways.

Comment: I meant, that i dont want to only shutdown the pc but also close all programs. 

The func. Process.Start() have other functions?

Comment: I just explained to you that shutting down a PC does close the programs. It tries to gracefully close them, then it tries to ungracefully close them. That's how shutting down a PC works unless you do a hard kill (hold the power button) in which case everything dies because there is no longer power to any of the components. `Process.Start` just executes a command as if at the command prompt. So we leveraged the built in [shutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx) command, which is capable of turning off remote PC's. You might also experiment with the `-f` flag.

Comment: Yes you did. But you didnt understand me. 
I want to have a option where i shut down the pc, and another option where i DONT shutdown the pc and just close all programs.

I think this will help me correct? : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8cwe1nij4Y

Comment: You should explain yourself clearer then, because I don't think anyone would have understood that from your previous comment. What do you mean exactly by "shut down all running programs"? I don't think you'll find that will be easy. What constitutes a running program? Just the programs you see in your taskbar? I suppose you could get a list of all processes that are executed by the current user and not a system service (SYSTEM, NETWORK SERVICE, LOCAL SERVICE, etc) and then kill those. It'd be easier to just log the user off the computer, which can be accomplished by the shutdown command.

Comment: Ill probaply just make the user log of then. And what i meant was to close all the programs you see on your task bar.

Another question, to run the "Process.Start("shutdown","-s -m \\\\" + pc);", do i need to be an admin of the comp. or of the domain, and does the target pc have to have something activated for it to work?

Comment: I'd assume you need to be an admin on that PC. Which shouldn't be a problem if you're actually authorized to shut down all the PC's. There's probably a service that needs to be running on the target PC. But the service will be bundles with the computer and probably listed if you run "services.msc". By the way- why are you asking me all this and not *actually trying it out*? Open up a command prompt, run the shutdown command with the -m and -f flags, and try it against a test computer and see how it works. You learn better by doing.

Comment: Yeah i have authorization. But im at home, and i dont have a network to try it here. And in school i have limited time with the computers so i cant wait for the answers of the forum, so i try to go to school with as many info as i can :) :)